# Apply a color to headings from the parent div using tailwindcss

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to achieve a utility class much like .prose does with headings:text-color-value
I've created a plugin which looks like my IDE picks up, but the value is not getting rendered in the compiled CSS. Is there something fundamentally wrong with this code, or should I be doing something entirely different?

```
module.exports = function ({ addUtilities, theme }) {
    const colors = theme('colors');

    const headingColorUtilities = Object.keys(colors).reduce((utilities, color) => {
        const colorShades = colors[color];

        if (typeof colorShades === 'object') {
            const colorUtility = Object.keys(colorShades).reduce((colorUtility, shade) => {
                return {
                    ...colorUtility,
                    [`.h2s\\:text-${color}-${shade}`]: {
                        '@apply text': colorShades[shade],
                    },
                };
            }, {});

            return {
                ...utilities,
                ...colorUtility,
            };
        }

        return utilities;
    }, {});

    addUtilities(headingColorUtilities);
};
```

i.e.

```
<div class="text-black headings:text-green-500">
<h2>This would be green<h2>
<p>This would be black</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something fundamentally wrong with this code, or should I be doing something entirely different?

Yes to both. It seems like you're after [a variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/plugins#adding-variants) with `addVariant()` that you'd do like:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant('headings', '& :is(h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6)');
    }),
  ]
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.3.2"></script>

<div class="text-black headings:text-green-500">
  <h2>This would be green</h2>
  <p>This would be black</p>
</div>
```